# How can I access Spring Webflow FlowScope elements outside the flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow-2

EDIT:   I didn't get any bites on this question, so I'm adding a little more detail.

I have a Spring Webflow app (ver 2.3.2).   I need to access multiple FlowScope objects from inside the validation of one of the steps (not inside the flow itself).     You would think this would be simple, but I haven't been able to crack it.

Spring Webflow provides a series of [special EL variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#el-variables) which can be used for accessing the various scopes, but only **inside** the flow itself.  Inside a custom Spring validator, there doesn't seem to be any way to get to them:

```
@Component
public class MyObjectValidator {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public void validateMyObject(MyObject myObject, Errors errors) {

        FlowScope flowScope = context.someMagicFunction();  //  <---- UNKNOWN  
        MyOtherObject otherObject = flowScope.get("otherObject");  

        if (incrediblyComplexValidation(myObject, otherObject) {
            errors.rejectValue("myField","validation.fail","Your object failed validation.");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, inside a [Spring Webflow Validator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-validate) there is no direct external linkage to anything except the object you are supposed to validate.    I need to get to those other objects  in the flowScope.   Ideally either through the `ApplicationContext` or some other environmental feature there must be a way to get to these other objects.

Anyone know the answer to this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the scope beans from RequestContext - context holder for request-specific statecurrent web application context. Access to request context in your validator method is by:

```
    import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;
    import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder;

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    requestContext.getFlowScope().get("objectYouAreLookingFor");
```

Comment: I get null when I try to get the values. Do you know how to pass the request context